# How can I increase the size of the console inside the code

Tags: windows, console, lazarus, freepascal

I'm doing some code in pascal using lazarus IDE v1.8.4, as the question says I need to be able to edit the console size in the code, I also preferably need to get the max possible console width they can have. If you do know how please also let me know the uses you.. used. Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958130/changing-the-console-size)?  It's for Delphi but ought to work in Lazarus/FPC.

Comment: I tried it, but no luck, I might be missing the uses for it though. I will check in a bit.

Comment: *I tried it, but no luck* That *try* (the code) should be in your post to show what you've done. It also helps if you include information on what OS you're using when you ask about a compiler that supports multiple platforms - a *console* can refer to the Windows console, the *nix terminal, or a gaming device.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that probably should have occurred to me to add it, especially given the issue was actually just me missing windows in uses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're targeting Windows:

- Use [`GetLargestConsoleWindowSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getlargestconsolewindowsize) to retrieve the largest possible console size depending on the console font and display settings,
- Use [`SetConsoleScreenBufferSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolescreenbuffersize) to set the console screen buffer to the largest possible size,
- Use [`SetConsoleWindowInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolewindowinfo) to set the size and position of the console's window, so that no scrollbars would be visible by default etc..

At this point the console's window should be positioned as you've set. With my tests, however, while the window complies with the sizing request, the position is ignored.

In that case use any API function to move the window, the below examples uses `SetWindowPos`. I had to declare [`GetConsoleWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow) as it was not declared in Lazarus 1.6.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  windows;

function GetConsoleWindow: HWND; stdcall external 'kernel32';

var
  Con: THandle;
  Size: TCoord;
  Rect: TSmallRect;
  Wnd: HWND;
begin
  Con := GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  Size := GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(Con);

  SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(Con, Size);

  Rect.Left := -10;
  Rect.Top := -10;
  Rect.Right := Size.X - 11;
  Rect.Bottom := Size.Y - 11;
  SetConsoleWindowInfo(Con, True, Rect);

  Wnd := GetConsoleWindow;
  SetWindowPos(Wnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOZORDER);

  Readln;
end.
```

And don't forget to add error checking.

Comment: Excellent answer. For reference, Delphi 10.3 Rio does not include `GetConsoleWindow` in `WinAPI.Windows` either.

Comment: I generally set the buffer to a **much** larger size than the window, especially in the vertical dimension (many many lines, like 3000 or 4000).

Comment: Wonderful, I hadn't realised I needed the windows in uses, thanks so much, I can finally get on with my project.

Comment: FPC 3.0.4 and thus current Lazarus versions should support getconsolewindow.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work fine in Lazarus for me on Win10Pro.

```
program ResizeConsoleWin;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows;

procedure SetConsoleWindowSize;
var
  Rect: TSmallRect;
  Coord: TCoord;
begin
  Rect.Left := 1;
  Rect.Top := 1;
  Rect.Right := 300;  // notice horiz scroll bar once the following executes
  Rect.Bottom := 30;
  Coord.X := Rect.Right + 1 - Rect.Left;
  Coord.y := Rect.Bottom + 1 - Rect.Top;
  SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Coord);
  SetConsoleWindowInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), True, Rect);
end;

begin
  SetConsoleWindowSize;
  readln;
end.
```

It's copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958130/changing-the-console-size) with only the window dimensions changed.